# Inline function error in downloaded libpqxx source

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, libpqxx

still trying to get libpqxx running, now when I import the library and the header <pqxx\pqxx> I get 19 error messages.

`E0325 inline specifier allowed on function declarations only`
and a error message about C2440  "const_Elem" can't be converted to "std::string"

and after opening the conversions.hxx where the inline specifier error lies, it adds more errors for constexpr being invalid here.

```
struct nullness<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>>> : no_null<T>
{};


template<> struct string_traits<short> : internal::integral_traits<short>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<short>{true};
template<>
struct string_traits<unsigned short>
        : internal::integral_traits<unsigned short>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<unsigned short>{true};
template<> struct string_traits<int> : internal::integral_traits<int>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<int>{true};
template<> struct string_traits<unsigned> : internal::integral_traits<unsigned>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<unsigned>{true};
template<> struct string_traits<long> : internal::integral_traits<long>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<long>{true};
template<>
struct string_traits<unsigned long> : internal::integral_traits<unsigned long>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<unsigned long>{true};
template<>
struct string_traits<long long> : internal::integral_traits<long long>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<long long>{true};
template<>
struct string_traits<unsigned long long>
        : internal::integral_traits<unsigned long long>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<unsigned long long>{true};
template<> struct string_traits<float> : internal::float_traits<float>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<float>{true};
template<> struct string_traits<double> : internal::float_traits<double>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<double>{true};
template<>
struct string_traits<long double> : internal::float_traits<long double>
{};
template<> inline constexpr bool is_unquoted_safe<long double>{true};
```

I use Visual Studio 2017, I was able to build the library without issues but now just the implementation gives me weird errors. I suspect that might be due to some settings in the compiler, but I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: Is this a c++17 feature?

Comment: I set my language standard to /std:c++17, but I think it is, yea

Comment: @PascalG Visual Studio doesn't necessarily implement all c++17 standard features properly and complete. Can you update to a newer Visual Studio version? You may check if it's listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it should be working with c++17, I recently updated to the newest version of VS2017, I will try later with 2019, maybe it will work there.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! It works on Visual Studio 2019 now, the inline constexpr errors are gone, but I still have the C2440 "const_Elem" can't be converted to "std::string" errors....

Comment: Maybe you need to provide more relevant information to slove C2440.